# Are there public laws dealing with extraterrestrial contact?

Tags: law, aliens, ufo

UFO theorists claim that there are US laws preventing people from investigating or contacting aliens.

From "Alien Contact Laws- $5,000 Fine And Imprisonment" at http://www.unexplainable.net/artman/publish/article_223.shtml

> Already Passed by Congress On October
>   5, 1982, Dr. Brain T. Clifford of the
>   Pentagon announced at a press
>   conference ("The Star", New York, Oct.
>   5, 1982) that contact between U.S.
>   citizens and extra-terrestrials or
>   their vehicles is strictly illegal.
>   According to a law already on the
>   books  (Title 14, Section 1211 of the
>   Code of Federal Regulations, adopted
>   on July 16, 1969, before the Apollo
>   moon shots), anyone guilty of such
>   contact automatically becomes a wanted
>   criminal to be jailed for one year and
>   fined $5,000.

From 
"UFO theorists gain support abroad, but repression at home"
at http://www.ufoevidence.org/documents/doc598.htm
we have this claim of censorship regulations:

> If the US military is concerned about
>   UFOs, it is not saying so publicly.
>   Indeed, the French report chastises
>   the United States for what it calls an
>   ''impressive repressive arsenal'' on
>   the subject, including a policy of
>   disinformation and military
>   regulations prohibiting public
>   disclosure of UFO sightings.
>
> Air Force Regulation 200-2,
>   ''Unidentified Flying Objects
>   Reporting,'' for example, prohibits
>   the release to the public and the
>   media of any data about ''those
>   objects which are not explainable.''
>   An even more restrictive procedure is
>   outlined in the Joint Army Navy Air
>   Force Publication 146, which threatens
>   to prosecute anyone under its
>   jurisdiction - including pilots,
>   civilian agencies, merchant marine
>   captains, and even some fishing
>   vessels - for disclosing reports of
>   sightings relevant to US security.

[image: Image borrowed from area51.stackexchange.com]

Picture credit:  area51.stackexchange.com server error page

**Is there evidence that these, or similar laws or regulations exist?**
**Is it specifically illegal to investigate a crashed spaceship yourself, chat with the occupants, or discuss such a "genuine" event with others?**

Comment: Hi Paul, your question is off topic because it does not relate to skepticism. What are you being skeptical about? Please correct and improve and the community or moderators will reopen. Thank you :-)

Comment: Sounds like I need to cite others' beliefs that there exists a body of law dealing with extraterrestrial contact.

Comment: it is to be noted that Unidentified Flying Object is not necessarily of extraterrestrial origin (or saucer-shaped for that matter); an Unidentified Flying Object is just an object which the observer cannot identify.

Comment: After my edits to shorten and clean up this question, if someone wants to take an additional crack at editing it, be my guest.

Comment: @Lie Yes, most everything you see in the sky is a UFO.  "Unidentified" does not mean spaceship. If you see one, or the other, is it illegal to discuss it? Some people believe it is. Thats the question.

Comment: @fNek Answers in comments tend to be deleted by moderators. If you can find actual treaty or law from a primary source like the UN or US Govt with a web search, you should post it as an answer. Conspiracy theorists may say there are secret laws or orders. Perhaps, or perhaps existing military procedures would cover any ... uninvited landing by foreign powers.. But skeptics is fact and citation based so it matters that a claim can be proven from reliable sources.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to these references:

1. **Snopes research**: http://www.snopes.com/legal/et.asp
2. **CFR Title 14, Section 1211** text and removal: http://www.textfiles.com/ufo/etxpos.txt

   (Alternate at http://paul.rutgers.edu/~mcgrew/ufo/cfr.1211 and others, could not be found on any .gov sites)
3. **Current Code of Federal Regulations Title 14**: http://www.access.gpo.gov/nara/cfr/waisidx_01/14cfrv5_01.html

The law **did exist**, but **did not make contact illegal**.  Specifically, it made **quarantine** by the US government of an exposed person (exposed to any celestial body, such as the moon by the Apollo 11 crew) legal, in the event that any danger (think Andromeda Strain) was present (1211.104.a.3):

> Determine that a
>   particular person, property, animal, or other form of life or matter
>   whatever is extraterrestrially exposed and quarantine such person,
>   property, animal, or other form of life or matter whatever.  The quarantine
>   may be based only on a determination, with or without the benefit of a
>   hearing, that there is probable cause to believe that such person, property,
>   animal or other form of life or matter whatever is extraterrestrially
>   exposed.

It has, apparently, been removed from the the books.  The official **.gov** site for Title 14 simply says "Reserved" (3rd link), but the second link above contains supposed text of a 1991 removal of the quarantine section of the code:

> **Summary:** NASA is removing 14 CFR part 1211 since it has served its 
>   purpose and is no longer in keeping with current policy.
>   **Effective Date:** April 26, 1991.

Comment: [Needs more blockquotes.](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/164/too-much-block-quoting/315#315) :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz - Fair enough, does that suffice?

Comment: lolz @sklivvz and Renesis :D

Comment: It certainly suffices for my upvote! +1

Comment: #3 is the correct place to go if it is public law.  Presumably the more factual sites could lead you there.

Comment: So in short, no conspiracy - just common sense. We have no idea what's out there, and if someone comes back with something bad the person in charge on the ground needs the authority to make the call to quarantine him right then and there without having to go through channels first. Plenty of time for the shouting and the committees and the hearings once everyone's sure the possible danger is contained.